# SQL alchemy not updating as expected

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This SQL Alchemy 0.9.7 code executes without error -- but does not update the underlying database as expected.

Here is the python:

```
    print t        #prints TITLE ABSTRACTOR 1
    print newtitle #prints TITLE ABSTRACTOR I
    print session.query(Basic).filter(Basic.title==t).count() #prints 1
    ret = update(Basic).where(Basic.title==t).values(title=newtitle)
    session.commit()
```

Here is what the database looks like after the update:

```
select count(*) from basics where title='TITLE ABSTRACTOR 1';
 count 
-------
     1
(1 row)

select count(*) from basics where title='TITLE ABSTRACTOR I';
 count 
-------
     0
(1 row)
```

Have I hit a SQL alchemy bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you give us a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Also, by ".9" do you mean 0.9.0? If so, the obvious thing to do would be to test with the latest version (0.9.7). If that works, then yes, you've hit a bug, and that bug has been fixed, and you're done. If not, then you still have to search bug reports or debug the code or hope someone else can do it, but at least people don't have to have the exact same older version as you to do so.

Comment: @abarnert I updated to latest version on pip, 0.9.7. same issue.

Comment: OK, that helps. But we still don't have an example (database dump, sqlalchemy setup, etc.) that anyone can either run, or read over, so nobody's going to be able to do much for you unless the bug is really obvious. The MCVE help link I provided above really will help you get better answers.

Comment: Hold on, speaking of really obvious bugs… I haven't used sqlalchemy in a while, but doesn't `update` just construct an `Update` object, which you then have to either call `execute` on, or pass to a connection's `execute` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just constructing an update statement:

```
ret = update(Basic).where(Basic.title==t).values(title=newtitle)
```

That doesn't do anything unless you execute the statement:

```
stmt = update(Basic).where(Basic.title==t).values(title=newtitle)
ret = conn.execute(stmt)
```

---

But I think you were trying to use the ORM interface, not the core interface. In which case, although I don't remember the details, I'm pretty sure you do that by modifying a query object, not by calling anything named `update`. Hopefully if this is what you're looking for, hopefully someone who's fresher on this will provide a better answer, but something like this:

```
ret = session.query(Basic).filter(Basic.title==t)
ret.title = newtitle
```

---

If this doesn't make sense to you, see [Executing](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/tutorial.html#executing) in the tutorial. But I'm guessing you know this and it was just one of those stupid bugs we all make and all have a hard enough time seeing in other people's code, and it's 100x worse in our own. :)